# how do I convert a decimal number to binary number using an algorithm

Tags: c++

We were given this question in class to go and write an algorithm for converting a decimal number to binary number and tomorrow present it, I myself had tried the question.

1. start
2. i=0, count=0
3. if i<=n goto step 4
4. r=n%2
5. n=n/2
6. count= count+1
7. store remainder
8. if count=9 true print number
9. else goto step 3
10. end

Comment: Please, show us [MRE]

Comment: Actually, your wording is wrong: There are no such things like decimal, binary or hexadecimal numbers. A number is a number, it has a concrete value that's always the same. It only can have different *representations*...

Comment: What makes you so sure that a number has exactly 9 binary digits???

Comment: @Aconcagua I think we know what the asker here means, no need to nitpick like that. The question about the length is more interesting.

Comment: @Cubic Maybe should have declared it as *'side note'* (was intended as help for future questions). Still don't underestimate the importance of correct wording, I've seen quite a number if misunderstandings arise just because of failing at having clear definitions, sometimes with heavy consequences...

Comment: @NutCracker: MREs are for debugging problems in existing code, not for every question. This question is ambiguous; we do not know if the OP has code that is not working or if they do not know how to write code from this algorithm. The question ought to be clarified before asking for an MRE, or the request for an MRE should be contingent on whether they have code that is misbehaving.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I appreciate what you're saying. I thought OP has some code that he might want to share with us. However, I might be wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more STL-ish and C++-ish solution, I suggest you using [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) (introduced in C++11) which represents a fixed-size sequence of N bits.

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

std::string int_to_binary(int const value) {
    std::bitset<sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT> bs(value);
    return bs.to_string();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << int_to_binary(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int_to_binary(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int_to_binary(3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:'%23include+%3Cbitset%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cclimits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astd::string+int_to_binary(int+const+value)+%7B%0A++++std::bitset%3Csizeof(int)+*+CHAR_BIT%3E+bs(value)%3B%0A++++return+bs.to_string()%3B%0A%7D%0A+%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+int_to_binary(1)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+//+0001%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+int_to_binary(2)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+//+0010%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+int_to_binary(3)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+//+0011%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Furthermore, if you want to make your `int_to_binary` function a bit more generic, you could turn it into a template function and take some time and research about SFINAE and [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Here is how your function now could look like:

```cpp
template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
std::string int_to_binary(T const value) {
    std::bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT> bs(value);
    return bs.to_string();
}
```

Comment: I'd multiply the size yet with `CHAR_BIT`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to cover larger values...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for suggestion. I have updated my example

Comment: Only drawback now is that you'd get all those many leading zeros. On the other hand, that can be an advantage, too, as you'd get proper two's complement for negative values ;) – I like that solution...

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah, i agree with you on that one. I suppose it is better to be correct and get proper output for negative values than care about something being pretty